# The request was rejected because its size exceeds the configured maximum

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, multipart

I have a WAR application with two servlets deployed into a Tomcat7 server. One of these servlets is to all catch RESTfull web service.
When I try to upload a file (with multipart mode); the server throws the follwing exception:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (2539037) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:110)
```

Answer (score 3):

create application.properties file under src/java/resources. Then simply add.

```
spring.http.multipart.maxFileSize = 25 MB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it only defining the  tag into the serlvet; attributes are needless:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```